# linear independence after subtraction of vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence

Given a set $\{v_0, v_1, v_2\}$ of linearly independent vectors, what happens if I subtract each vector of that set by, say, $v_0$?

Then I obtain the set $\{0, v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0\}$. However, since any family of vectors containing the zero vector is dependent, this would mean that our new set is now dependent, right? But that again would mean that the dimension of the first set was 3 and that of the second is 2. So this would mean that I can reduce the dimension of a set by subtracting vectors?

Now, if I look at $span\{v_0, v_1, v_2\}$ and $span\{v_0, v_1, v_2\} - v_0$. Is the latter set equal to $span\{0, v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0\}$ and does this set again have one dimension less than the span without subtracting a vector?

Comment: $\{v_0, v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0\}$ seems like a more interesting set of vectors

Comment: Think in one dimension for a moment...  You have the real number line.  Now... if you take every point on that real number line and subtract $1$ from each point on it... are you left with nothing or are you still left with a numberline just shifted to the side a bit?  Or if by $\text{span}\{v_0\}-v_0$ you mean that you remove the point $v_0$ from the result of the span, then you are left with a numberline with a missing hole at $1$... that wouldn't be a vectorspace anymore but would still be quite large, not empty and not just zero.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $span\{v_0, v_1, v_2\}-v_0=span\{v_0, v_1, v_2\}$, since a generic element of the former is of the form $a_0v_0+a_1v_1+a_2v_2-v_0=(a_0-1)v_0+a_1v_1+a_2v_2$, and any linear combination of $v_0, v_1, v_2$ can be expressed in this way.

So $span\{v_0, v_1, v_2\}-v_0$ has dimension $3$, while $span\{0, v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0\}=span\{v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0\}$ has dimension $2$, hence they cannot be equal.

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{span}\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}-v_0$?

Comment: Let $A=\operatorname{span}\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}$, then $A-v_0=\{a-v_0: a\in A\}$.

Comment: And so? What do you get? Just $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$span\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}$ is a vector space of dimension $3$ while $span\{v_0-v_0,v_1-v_0,v_2-v_0\}$ is always a vector space of dimension $3-1=2$ but $span\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}-v_0$ is not even a vector space, due to the lack of closure property with respect to the addition. For instance; $span\{(1,0),(0,1\}-(1,0)=\mathbb R^2-(1,0)$ is not a vector space as it misses the sum  $(1,1)+(0,-1)$.

**EDIT**: After one of the users pointed out that OP defined $A-v=\{a-v:a\in A\}$, here is the modified part of my original answer. The set $span\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}-v_0$ is essentially the same vector space as $span\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}$ due to the closure property between vector '$-v_0$' and an arbitrary vector of $span\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}$ which implies the equality of two sets.

Comment: You’re viewing $A-v$ as $A \setminus \{v\} = \{a \in A : a \neq v\}$, but OP uses that notation for $\{a-v : a \in A\}$.

Comment: Thanks @azif00 for pointing out this.  I have made an edit.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer and the edit. So you re writing in your edit that they are "essentially the same vector space". Is there still a difference or are they really equal? Can this be proven by a simple proof?

And regarding the situation with $span\{v_0-v_0, v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0\}$ is that the same as $span\{v_1-v_0, v_2-v_0\}$, i.e., can I drop the 0 vector from that set and still obtain the same linear hull?

Comment: Yes these are same vector space. An intuition about this is to think about vector $-v_0$ which is additive inverse of vector $v_0$ so that the result $v_i-v_0, v_i\in V$ always lie in $V$ itself due to the closed nature of vector space $V$. For your second question, the answer is YES as the zero vector doesn't contribute at all, if present in the spanning set.